# How to Get data from datagridview in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net

I have a datagridview. User enter data in datagridview. Now I want to get data from datagridview to datatable.

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Comment: BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dataGridView2.DataSource;
DataTable dat = (DataTable)(bs.DataSource);

Comment: but dataGridView2.DataSource is null

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int rows = 0; rows < dataGrid.Rows.Count; rows++)
{
     for (int col= 0; col < dataGrid.Rows[rows].Cells.Count; col++)
    {
        string value = dataGrid.Rows[rows].Cells[col].Value.ToString();
        //fill your model and prepare object to save in database
    }
}
```

You have to fetch data from grid in a model object and after that you have to send save call with that data.
Hope this is what you wanted

Comment: Thanks for answer. But is there any way to get from datagridview and hold in datatable like above